# how to uninstall old express(1) executable and update to latest

Tags: node.js, express

I updated to the latest express release candidate but it didn't seem to update the express(1) executable, which is stuck on version 2.4.3.  I tried

```
npm uninstall express -g
```

To no avail.  I also tried

```
npm update express -g
```

Which seems to have updated my express files in /usr/local/lib to 3.0.0rc4 but the express(1) executable still shows version 2.4.3 when I do express -v

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you update express to the latest version with:

```
$ npm install -g express
```

I was going from express `3.0.0rc3` release, to `3.1.0`. The newest versions places the express(1) executable at `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/express`

but checking the version:

```
$ express --version
3.0.0rc3
```

That's not right. I just installed 3.1.0, what's going on?

I came here and saw Peter Lyons answer:

```
$ which express
/usr/local/bin/express
```

Yeah that's not right, I want the one at `/usr/local/share/npm/bin/express`. So I deleted it based on his answer, and:

```
$ express --version
-bash: express: command not found
```

What the eff? Ahhh, I need to either quit the terminal (cmd+Q) and restart it. Or as Peter has commented below use `hash -r` to refresh the path hashes.

When that's done:

```
$ which express
/usr/local/share/npm/bin/express
$ express --version
3.1.0
```

Good, its fixed! Now back to what I was actually going to do with express...I can't even remember now.

Comment: You can use the bash command `hash -r` (`rehash` for zshell) after directories on your PATH change to recompute the command hash instead of quitting the terminal entirely. `exec $SHELL` will also get the job done.

Answer (score 1):

Type `which express` to see where the executable is in your filesystem. You probably have more than one version installed and once you understand which is where you can uninstall/delete them.

Comment: I deleted the file that was indicated by the which command, but it didn't seem to help since it looked like it was still trying to find the old deleted file and which was pointing to a file that didn't exist.